# wifiManager.addNetwork fails

Tags: android, wifi

I have a server who is another android device. The server starts a wifi hotspot.
On my client i try to connect automatically to the hotspot.

I call this function in a new Thread in onStart():

```
private void enableWifi(){
    if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        Log.i("Wifi", "Wifi enabled");
    }
    if(getNetworkId() == -1){
        addNetwork();
    }
    while(!isConnected(context)){
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(getNetworkId(),true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        Log.i("Wifi", "Connecting to Hotspot");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TIMEOUT);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Wifi", "Thread interrupted: " + e);
        }
    }

    Log.i("Wifi", "Connected to Hotspot");
}

private int getNetworkId(){
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + wifiName + "\"")) {
            return i.networkId;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private void addNetwork(){
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\\" + wifiName + "\\";
    wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\\" + wifiPassword + "\\";
    wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
    Log.i("Wifi", "Added Hotspot to configured Networks");
}
```

wifiManager.addNetwork() returns -1

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make it clear what your actual question is and what you already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that you're putting back-slashes instead of quotes in the SSID and password.

Try this:

```
wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + wifiName + "\"";
wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + wifiPassword + "\"";
```